# django must be installed on server that is located in apache?

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

When I read django doc, apache config file should be configured as below

```
<Directory /tutorial/django/tutorial/tutorial/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
</Directory>
```

It means django must be installed on the same server running apache. Right?

As I know, apache and tomcat can be located on other server.

architecture is like below.

> apache - load balancer -tomcat

But Django must be like below?

> load balancer - apache(+django)

If yes, there is any reason ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can run Django in another server with the help of something like Gunicorn - then you must use something like mod_proxy instead of mod_wsgi to make apache talk to it. AFAIK yes, mod_wsgi assumes you are running Django in the same machine.

Comment: @PauloScardine thanks. it is helpful to understand it.